How to update GD version library image to support avif?
I have updated ImageMagick and added Avif support via libheif-dev, but GD does not know how to use these photos. I need to update it. I also later installed libavif-dev, but never figured out how to connect it.
Here is version 2.2.5 and support for ImageMagick Avif
More information about ImageMagick
I tried to install libgd3, but I still have the old version 2.2.5
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. php version is currently 8.2. Who is more experienced in this and can help? I have searched for all the information on the Internet and am learning on my own.
